# jquery.transit - how to pass translate to element's "right" attribute instead of "left"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-transit

I want to use jquery transit and I want it to work reversed. And I mean right to left.

for example:

```
$('.box').transition({ x: '40px' });
```

will move the 'box' 40px to right.

but i want it to move to left.

I know that I can pass negative value to that and make it move to left but I can't do that either, because in my situation, the parent has the whole screen width and negative left would move the 'box' out of the screen.

so if i could anyway pass transition x to the element's "right" instead of "left" my problem would be solved.

Comment: not negative left would not move the 'box' out of the screen??

Answer (score 0):

have you tried something like this??

```
$('.box').css('left','+=40px').transition({ x: '-40px' });
```